# How do I convert a std::filesystem::directory_entry to a std::string?

Tags: c++, filesystems

so i am trying to convert the files to a std string but it doesn't work can anyone help? thanks

```
std::string path = "C:\\";
    for (const auto& entry : fs::directory_iterator(path)) {
        std::string files = entry.path();
    }
```

Comment: I am using Windows

Comment: What does "it doesn't work" mean?

Comment: On windows you need `entry.path().string()`.  `path` on windows returns a `std::wstring`.

Comment: @NathanOliver "*`path` on windows returns a `std::wstring`*" - more accurately, `directory_entry::path()` always returns a `std::filesystem::path`, which then has an *implicit conversion* to `std::wstring` on Windows (to `std::string` on Posix).